# missing or invalid schema element (ON CREATING SCHEMA)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to create new schema in
`https://apex.oracle.com` `workspace`
but showing an error

#### ORA-02422: missing or invalid schema element

```
  CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION NI***@GMAIL.COM
  
     CREATE TABLE new_product 
        (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER) 
     CREATE VIEW new_product_view 
        as select COLOR, QUANTITY from NEW_PRODUCT where COLOR = 'RED' 
     GRANT select ON new_product_view TO NI***@GMAIL.COM
  ;
```

Comment: Is NI***@GMAIL.COM a valid username in Oracle?

Comment: ya it is valid ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The schema name on apex.oracle.com is the workspace name, which is not necessarily the same as the username you use to login.

Schema names with non-standard characters must be referenced using double quotes:

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION "NI***@GMAIL.COM"
 CREATE TABLE new_product 
    (color VARCHAR2(10)  PRIMARY KEY, quantity NUMBER)
```